# How to print all elements by id (JS,PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

I have some list from db using foreach, and now i would like to when i press button print to print all elements with "print" id, but in my case when i click print i only can print first item in list, not all.

```
    <?php $unos = $db->odradi("SELECT * FROM books WHERE cust='$cust' ORDER BY id ASC"); 
   if (!empty($unos)) { 
   foreach($unos as $podatak=>$value){ 
    $r_id=$unos[$data]['id'];
   ?>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2" id="print"> 
    <div class="well well-sm bg-color-light txt-color-black text-center">

    <small><?php echo $db[$data]['name'] ?></small><br>
    <img alt="<?php echo $unos[$data]['name'] ?>" src="barcode.php?codetype=Code39&size=40&text=<?php echo
    $unos[$data]['id'] ?>&print=true" />
    </div>    </div>      <?php }
    } ?>
    <button onclick="printaj()">Print all</button>
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
function printaj() {
var prtContent = document.getElementById("print");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: ids have to be unique.... not sure if you mean you have more than one.

Comment: i.e., `var prtContent = document.getElementById("print");` gets ONE SINGLE ELEMENT, the first one with that ID ... why not create a containing div that contains all this, with id=print - simplest code change, then you wont need to iterate through a bunch of divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id's in HTML must be unique - you create multiple `id=print` and `document.getElementById` will return a single element

If it returned multiple elements, your code would still fail, since your code relies on the fact that `document.getElementById` returns a single element!

So, I'd suggest a single outer div with id=print as follows

```
<?php 
    $unos = $db->odradi("SELECT * FROM books WHERE cust='$cust' ORDER BY id ASC"); 
    if (!empty($unos)) {
?>
        <div id="print">
<?php
        foreach($unos as $podatak=>$value){ 
            $r_id=$unos[$data]['id'];
?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2"> 
                <div class="well well-sm bg-color-light txt-color-black text-center">
                    <small><?php echo $db[$data]['name'] ?></small><br>
                    <img alt="<?php echo $unos[$data]['name'] ?>" src="barcode.php?codetype=Code39&size=40&text=<?php echo $unos[$data]['id'] ?>&print=true" />
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
<button onclick="printaj()">Print all</button>
```

With this solution, `printaj` does not need to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: use class name instead of ID and itterate through class objects:

```
function printaj() {
var prtContent ;
var content= document.getElementsByClassName("print");
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++)
{
  prtContent =prtContent +content(i).innerHTML;
}
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
}
```

solution 2:
wrap all generated content inside a single div with `id="print"` and print it!